# Can I use Duke to immediately restore sanity right after I discover I'm going to lose it?

Tags: arkham-horror

If I were to discover that losing sanity would drive me insane, can I use the ally Duke to immediately heal my sanity first?  It sounds like I would be cheating time doing this, so my thinking is that the answer is no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you couldn't use Duke in that situation. Certain cards such as Flesh Ward specifically allow interrupting the order of things to prevent you from taking damage, but Duke does not.

You would need to choose to use Duke before whatever action you were taking (such as drawing an encounter), or afterwards, but it cannot interrupt the resolution of a card once it has started.

From the [Arkham Horror Complete FAQ](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/Arkham_Horror/FAQs/Complete_Arkham_FAQ.pdf) (page 14):

> **Q:** When can a character perform actions during a phase?
>   For example, if a player with the ally Duke (“discard to
>   immediately restore your Sanity to its maximum”) draws
>   an encounter and has to roll a die and lose that much
>   Sanity, when can he discard Duke to restore Sanity: not at
>   all once the encounter card is drawn, before the roll, or
>   after the roll?
>
> **A:** He may discard Duke after the roll, provided he
>   has not been driven insane. Actions can be performed
>   at any time during their listed phase as long as any given
>   conditions are met. However, once an encounter is drawn,
>   it must be resolved before any more actions can be performed.
>   So, in the case of Duke, you can use him before
>   or after drawing an encounter card, but if you draw the
>   encounter card and it inflicts Sanity loss that reduces you
>   to 0 Sanity, you go insane before you can use Duke. Flesh
>   Ward is one exception to this rule because it prevents a
>   Stamina loss and is intended to be used in response to such
>   events. The Premonition Spell [CotDP] is another exception.